# How to copy/paste cells from a conditionally formatted sheet to another file or sheet with formatting but without conditional rules?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have an excel file "Book1" with conditional formatting enabled on "Sheet1".

Conditional rules are based on a formula.
For example, highlight the entire row blue if the value in the column A is even number.

This way, I am able to create odd and even row highlights, similar to banded rows, but in my case next row may continue the data for the same item, and I want cells to be filled with the same color for same item.

Now, I want to move this data to another file or share it as a report to someone, with the formatted rows, but without the conditional rules.

Is there a way to do that without the manual way of formatting all rows with desired format and then removing conditional formatting? That will basically take so much time for me to update all formatting options and defeats the purpose of conditional formatting.

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask your question in case you need further information. Request not to downvote the question as it is a genuine use case for me.

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=excel%20convert%20conditional%20format%20to%20static) reveals several solutions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692918/make-conditional-formatting-static)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad True, but they don’t give concrete answer. I have a lot of formatting going on through conditions. Writing every item as part of VBA code is painful. Further, excel and conditional formatting rule shall keep on changing in my case. So just wanted to ask it again if this was possible in any way without VBA. But guess it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### As you said in a comment you'd rather not use VBA, I suggest to you this method:

1. Finish editing your original workbook and save it normally.
2. Save this Workbook as a Web Page (*.html) with a different name. (Affirm the warning.)
3. Open that HTML file with Excel.
   (File – Open – It should be in Recent, otherwise use Browse)
4. If you have multiple Sheets:
   Click on the first Sheet's name, then hold Shift and click on the last Sheet's name.
5. Open the View tab and enable Gridlines.
6. Save the open Workbook as an Excel Workbook (*.xlsx).
7. (You can now delete the HTML file.)

This makes the formatting static, but also only transfers the values, not the formulas you used to get them.

###### If you want to keep the formulas, do the following after:

1. Switch to your original Workbook and open the first Sheet.
2. Mark everything and copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).
3. Switch back to the new Workbook.
4. Mark everything or select A1.
5. Right click and choose "Formulas" (Clipboard with "fx") under "Paste Options".
   Alternatively, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then immediately press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> again and then press <kbd>F</kbd>.
6. Repeat for every Sheet.

###### Disclaimer:

This method was suggested by *Ashish Anand* and *jlear* in [the Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62267643/17239990) already linked by me and *cybernetic.nomad*, I just combined it and added the part about gridlines.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to make your conditional formatting "permanent" in the new workbook, meaning independent of the values, correct?

###### If you aren't averse to using VBA for this, you can adapt the code snippet below:

```vb
Public Sub MakeFormattingPermanent()
    Dim currentCell As Range
    For Each currentCell In Selection
        currentCell.Interior.Color = currentCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
End Sub
```

This works for the background color of your current selection specifically, but can be easily adapted for other things by replacing `Interior.Color` with for example `Font.Bold` for bold formatting, or similar.

So, copy everything from the old to the new workbook, open the editor on the new workbook (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>), paste the code into the module `ThisWorkbook`, select your cells and press the green "play"-symbol to start the sub. Then just save the workbook as a standard `.xlsx`, which will not save the code.

###### Disclaimer:

I adapted the Code from [this StackOverflow answer by pooroldpedro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52724031/17239990).